# Visualising ground radar in QGIS using rendering

Tags: qgis, raster, visualisation, rendering

I have GPRI intensity ground based radar data as data validation for my SAR analysis.

As this does not appear to be a multi-band image, how do I render this on QGIS so I can see my targets?

I have clicked on Properties to look at the Symbology and fiddled about with some settings for a better visualisation, but not having much luck.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to show the `raster` toolbar (in the `View > Toolbars` menu) ? You can adjust the grayscale for the whole raster or just the portion displayed.

Comment: Set rendering to Singleband pseudocolor. You can also limit the spectrum by manually adjusting min/max values to limit rendering to certain value range

Comment: Also: what are your targets? how would you expect to identify them based on the SAR values?

Comment: My targets are icebergs, bright dots that show up on the SAR images. Thanks for all the suggestions. I appreciate it.

Comment: So what is your question? Did the steps proposed above help you? If not, please be more specific, edit the initial question and add more details. Like this, it's difficult to help.